# Can BDD acceptance criteria format (Given - When - Then) be used for technical debt or tasks?

Tags: agile, bdd

Behavior-driven development is meant to be used at the business/user level.

However, I find the keywords "Given - When - Then" a good format for technical stories as well, but I am very green, and so maybe I'm missing something?

Is there a better format to track technical debt, or tasks under user stories?

Comment: I find given-when-then annoying in technical stories. It makes easier to understand business concepts, but trying to fit complex technical concepts into that makes people do some grammar, language and cognitive gymnastics that make things hard to understand.

Comment: can you give an example? GIVEN we want to use DI, WHEN we write the superservice THEN it should have an interface?

Comment: A note to some of our community members: down-votes are not meant for ideas you disagree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behavior-driven development is far more than the Given-When-Then format of Gherkin and Gherkin-like languages.

BDD is an evolution of test-driven development (TDD) and acceptance test-driven development (ATDD). BDD adds a domain-specific language to be able to express expected outcomes. BDD tools use these domain-specific languages to open the ability to read and write tests to a broader audience.

Although I see value in TDD, ATDD, and BDD, I don't see a lot of value when using Given-When-Then for most cases. In my experience, the people writing the tests are usually technical people. The people who would be best served by being able to read and write tests written in these kinds of domain-specific languages aren't reading and writing tests. The kind of structures imposed add more overhead than value.

I've found that more free-form expressions of the desired state of the system tend to be more useful. Not only does this include less structured human-language text, but it also includes tabular or graphical representations of the desired state of the system. The technical team would then be able to transform these free-form expressions into designs and tests using the appropriate tools, which includes using TDD and other test-first practices. And sometimes, those tools (especially testing tools) may use a Given-When-Then structure, but that isn't a prerequisite.

I would especially find the expression of technical debt in a Given-When-Then format to be extremely verbose. The types of work that are involved in paying back technical debt shouldn't result in changes to the system. The verification of technical debt should not require the creation or modification of test cases, especially at the system or acceptance levels. Changing outward-facing behavior would not fall into the category that I'd consider to be paying down technical debt.

Answer (score -1):

If the current behaviour is different and wrong, then this is fine. “Technical debt” is usually used for code that is unreliable or hard to maintain. If the behaviour is (mostly) fine then you handle it differently.

If the behaviour is wrong then you can request a change in behaviour, and the developers agree that the best way to implement it is to first remove technical debt to make the behaviour change easier or possible at all.

At an extreme you could have a requirement given - when - then the application does what it should do without crashing.